# Maximising a Linear Programming Problem

Tags: linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

Maximize $w=2x+3y+6z$ subject to

$2x+y+z \le 5$

$3y+2z \le 6$

$x,y,z  \ge 0$

Is the optimal solution unique? Justify your answer.

I tried to solve it by Simplex method. In the second iteration, I got the optimal solution condition and the optimum solution is $z=3,\; x=1, y=0$.
. Correct me if I have done anything wrong.

Also how to justify that there exists or doesn't an alternate optimum?

Comment: i have got $$30,x=0,y=0,z=5$$

Comment: That's right, $(0,0,5)$ is the optimal and unique.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution? Also how to justify that the optimal solution is unique?

Comment: There was some mistake in the second constraint. I have corrected it. Please check it.

Comment: @Balaji OK, the corrected problem has indeed the solution after two iterations as $(1,0,3)$. No non-basic column has zero in the top row of the simplex tableau, therefore, the solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

/* Objective function */
max: 2x + 3y + 6z;
2x+y+z <= 5;
3y+2z <= 6;

/* Variable bounds */
x >= 0;
y >= 0;
z >= 0;

x = 1, y = 0, z = 3

Optimal solution                  20 after          2 iter.
Relative numeric accuracy ||*|| = 0

MEMO: lp_solve version 5.5.2.5 for 32 bit OS, with 64 bit REAL variables.
In the total iteration count 2, 0 (0.0%) were bound flips.
There were 0 refactorizations, 0 triggered by time and 0 by density.
... on average 2.0 major pivots per refactorization.
The largest [LUSOL v2.2.1.0] fact(B) had 3 NZ entries, 1.0x largest basis.
The constraint matrix inf-norm is 3, with a dynamic range of 3.
Time to load data was 0.003 seconds, presolve used 0.008 seconds,
... 0.006 seconds in simplex solver, in total 0.017 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).